Does $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^x e^{y^2/2} \, dy \; e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$ exist?
I am trying to figure out if the following integral exists $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^x e^{y^2/2} \, dy \; e^{-x^2/2} \, dx $$
For higher potentials in the exponent of the exponential, say $x^4$, the existence of the corresponding integral can be proved with an application of L'Hôspital's rule, but for this Gaussian case, I am actually unsure. Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

The integrand is positive everywhere; you can choose $a>0$ and consider
$$\int_a^\infty(\int_a^xe^{y^2/2}dy)e^{-x^2/2}dx\overset{IBP}{=}\int_a^\infty\Big(\frac{e^{x^2/2}}x-\frac{e^{a^2/2}}a+\int_a^x\frac{e^{y^2/2}}{y^2}dy\Big)e^{-x^2/2}dx$$
$$>\int_a^\infty\Big(\frac{e^{x^2/2}}x-\frac{e^{a^2/2}}a\Big)e^{-x^2/2}dx,\to,\infty$$

Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

I'm afraid I misled you: the integrand is not positive everywhere, because $\int_0^x e^{y^2/2} dy<0$ for $x<0$. My apology. I will check more accurately.

Splitting the interval of variable $x, ,(-N_a;-a];,[b;N_b),(a, b,N_a,N_b>0)$
and integrating by parts $I=\displaystyle\lim_{a,b\to0;,N_a, N_b\to\infty}\big(I_b-I_a\big)$, where
$$I_a=\int_a^{N_a}\Big(\frac{e^{x^2/2}}x-\frac{e^{a^2/2}}a+\int_a^x\frac{e^{y^2/2}}{y^2}dy\Big)e^{-x^2/2}dx$$
Generally speaking, both $I_a, I_b$ diverge (and so the initial integral), but if we choose $a=b, N_a=N_b$, we do get zero due to the symmetry of the integrand.

Hint
Consider $$f(x)=\int_0^x e^{\frac{y^2}2} \,  e^{\frac{x^2}2} \, dy=e^{\frac{x^2}2}\int_0^x e^{\frac{y^2}2}\,dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\, e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$But
$$ \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + \text{erfi}\left(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=0$$ So, $f(x)$ is an odd function and integrated over a symetric interval, then $\cdots$ ?

This is the question of defining the divergent integral on the infinite interval. The result (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) is in our hands :)

Perhaps I should have formulated the question differently. Evidently, as @Svyatoslav has showed above, the improper integral does not exist in the Riemann sense. However, using the symmetry aspect it may be defined in the sense of Cauchy principal value, where it would, in fact, equal zero.

Here is an alternative approach where the integrand is tackled in the same manner as the gaussian integral when it is squared in order to take advantage of polar coordinates. Indeed, considering a change of variable towards some "hyperbolic polar coordinates", namely
$$
\begin{cases}
   x = r \cosh t \\
   y = r \sinh t
\end{cases},
$$
whose Jacobian is given by $\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,t)}\right| = r$, one has :
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x \int_0^x\mathrm{d}y\; e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2)} = \int_0^\infty re^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} \mathrm{d}r \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}t
$$
recalling that the domain of integration corresponds to the area between the axis of abscissa and the curve $y = x$. The radial integral is simply $1$, but the one with respect to $t$ is clearly divergent. Nonetheless, as mentioned in the comment section, you might consider a vanishing principal value because of the odd parity of the integrand over a symmetric interval, since
$$
\int_0^{-x} e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y = -\int_0^x e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y,
$$
due the change of variable $y \mapsto -y$.
